# Wolfram alpha - Newton's method error

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, newton-raphson

I realize errors always occur when I use online software, even for wolfram alpha.

[image]

I personally found the results with the first guess of 2 are

$$n_1 = 1.7..., \quad n_2=1.64....$$

and so on, but they are not shown in wolframalpha. Did I go something wrong? or is newton's method just not reliable?

Comment: 1) Did you mean to use the natural log? 2) for numerical methods, WolframAlpha often only shows the first couple/few iterations.

Comment: WA uses the natural log when you write $\log$

Comment: Ah, I know it writes $log$ when you type $ln$, but usually it says "log is the natural log" at the bottom right of the box if that's the case.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is not Wolfram but the hand calculation.  Starting with $n_0=2$, the correct value for the next step is $$n_1=2-\frac{(2^3-3)\log(2^3-3)}{3\cdot 2^2}\approx 1.3294$$

Alas, the hand method now grinds to a halt, as $n_1^3-3\approx -0.6505$, and you can't take the log of that without complex numbers.  Wolfram does indeed do this, but then the method grinds to a halt soon after, as the results spiral out on the complex plane and do not converge.